# Orthogonal diagonalizable for normal liner operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

**if normal liner operator over $\mathbb{R}$ have an eigenvalue than it Orthogonal Diagonalizable?**

I know that over $\mathbb{C}$ any normal operator is Orthogonal Diagonalizable and is not true over $\mathbb{R}$
my professor claim that is not true. however, the proof assumes that the filed is  $\mathbb{C}$ because its required an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand what you have written. I believe that you are trying to ask the following:

> Suppose that a normal linear operator over a (finite dimensional) real vector space has only real eigenvalues. Is it true that this operator must be orthogonally diagonalizable?

The answer to this question is yes. In particular, if a normal operator over a real vector space has only real eigenvectors, then this operator must be self-adjoint.

One proof of this statement is as follows: suppose that $V$ is an inner product space over $\Bbb R$ and $A:V \to V$ is normal.  We note that $A$ must have some eigenvector $v$. Because $A$ is normal, it holds that $w \perp v \implies Aw \perp v$. Thus, $v^\perp$ is an invariant subspace (with dimension smaller than that of $V$).  Moreover, we can see that the restriction $A|_{v^\perp}$ is normal.

With that, we can inductively show that $A$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis, so that it is orthogonoally diagonalizable. It follows that $A$ must be self-adjoint.

---

It is not true that $A$ is necessarily diagonalizable if it has a real eigenvalue. For example, the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}
$$
(the $90^\circ$ clockwise rotation in $\Bbb R^3$ about the $z$-axis) has a real eigenvalue of $1$ but fails to be diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$. So, it fails to be orthogonally diagonalizable.

Comment: Thak you.but I ask if normal operator have at least one real enginvalue. Not if all the enginvalue are real.

Comment: What is an "enginvalue"?

Comment: I ment eigenvalue